# How to mock express in nodejs when express app is located inside function?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, sinon

I have `httpListener.ts`, which looks like this:

```
export function startListening() {
     const app = express();
     app
         .use(bodyParser.json())
         .post('/home/about', func1)
         .get('/user/product/:id', func2)
         .use(function (req, res) {
             res.status(404).send(`no routing for path ${req.url}`);
         })
         .listen(httpListenerConfig.port, () => {
             console.log('listening..');
         });
 }
```

and I have to write unit tests for `func1` and `func2` (these functions are private),I want to invoke them using fake http request..

any idea?

Comment: *these functions are private* - then export them, at least for testability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use framework like superTest to test the http request. SuperTest needs the express app and so I am exporting the app. 
I am assigning app.listen to server so that the server can be closed (server.close) after the test.

**httpListener.js**

```
var express = require('express');
function startListening() {
    const app = express();
    app
        .get('/home/about', func1)
        .get('/user/product/:id', func2)
        .use(function (req, res) {
            res.status(404).send(`no routing for path ${req.url}`);
        })
        var server = app.listen(3001, () => {  //so the server can be closed after the test
            console.log('listening..');
        });
        module.exports = server; 
}
function func1 (req, res) {
    res.status(200).send('this is home - about page');
}
  function func2 (req, res) {
    res.status(200).send('this is product page');
}

startListening();
```

**httpListener-test.js**

```
var request = require('supertest');
describe('loading express', function () {
  var server;
  beforeEach(function () {
    server = require('./httpListner.js');
  });
  afterEach(function () {
    server.close();
  });
  it('responds to /home/about', function test(done) {
    request(server)
    .get('/home/about')
    .expect(200) //test status
    .expect('this is home - about page', done); //test the response string
  });
});
```

To test more on func1 and func2, you have to export them so it is available to test.